# FlatFileItemWriter not writing full records in mount drive

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We have a batch running in the AIX environment. The Batch read a data from sql server 2012 database table and writer to the file in the windows directory. Windows directory is mounted in AIX.

**Test 1:** 
We pointed the output file location to AIX directory and run the batch. 
**Result :** No issue and extracted all records.

**Test 2:** 
We pointed the output file location to Windows directory and run the batch.
**Result :** Not all the records extracted and no errors.

Code sample

```
    <bean id="XXXXWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
            <property name="resource" ref="outputResource" />
            <property name="lineAggregator">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator" />
            </property>
            <property name="transactional" value="false" />
    </bean>

<bean id="outputResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource"
        scope="step">
        <constructor-arg value="#{jobExecutionContext['fileLocation']}" />
    </bean>
```

**Note:** fileLocation = /xxx/batch/yyy/fff/ExtFiles/dddd.csv

Thanks for your reply in advance

**13-08-204: Update**
We found the AIX is override the files for some reasons. We don't know why the AIX is override the files.

Comment: what is the value of `outputResource`?

Comment: try with prefix `file:` as suggested in my post.

Comment: I will try.. But Why we need to add a prefix 'file'?

Comment: Are you storing the file under windows file system?

Comment: Yes.. Batch is running in AIX and write the file to the windows directory. windows directory is mounted in AIX.

Comment: sorry No idea about AIX. just try `<property name="resource" value="file:src/resources/data/output.txt" />` if it works.